# Delete the whole row from an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, unset

How do I delete the whole line from an array? When the delete-button is pressed it should delete the whole line.

my array looks like that:

```
$liste[0][0] = email-user1
$liste[0][1]= password-user1
$liste[1][0] = email-user2
$liste[1][1]= password-user2
```

So if I delete the user one, the user2 should just take the place from user1(which should just disappear).

```
 if (isset($_GET['delete'])){
   $id=key($_GET['delete']);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($liste); $i++){
        if ("$i"=="$id"){
            unset($liste[$id][0]);
            unset($liste[$id][1]);
            unset($liste[$id][2]);

        }
        else{

            }

    }
```

**update**

 I'm using `array_splice($liste, $id, 1);` now but everytime I try to save it to the file I get an error: `implode(): Invalid arguments passed`. For saving it to the file, I use the following function:

```
  function saveDataToFile($fileName, $liste){
    $file=fopen($fileName,"w");
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($liste); $i++) {
        $zArray=$liste[$i]; 
        $zeile=implode("|", $zArray);
        if(strlen($zeile) > 0){ 
            $zeile=$zeile."\r\n"; 
            fwrite($file, $zeile);
        }
    }
    fclose($datei);
}
```

Comment: Just unset the first key: `unset($liste[$id]);`

Comment: Arrays do not have "lines", they contain elements. If you just want to remove the element with key 0, then why does `unset($liste[$id])` not work?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_splice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) method:

```
array_splice($liste, $id, 1);
```

Comment: Is it possible that there is still a fault. I updated the post with my function to save it to the fiel, but I always get an error at the implode.

Comment: If you did not solve it yet, try to cast the second parameter of the implode method, like so: `$zeile=implode("|", (array)$zArray);`, and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```
$liste[0][0] = "email-user1";
$liste[0][1]= "password-user1";
$liste[1][0] = "email-user2";
$liste[1][1]= "password-user2";
$liste[2][0] = "email-user3";
$liste[2][1]= "password-user3";

unset($liste[1]); // say you want to delete this row
$new_arr = $liste;
unset($liste);
$i=0;
foreach($new_arr as $value){
    $liste[$i] = $value;
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: If you want to reset the array keys, you can also use `array_values()` after you unset the element, that would clean up your code a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`$liste[0][0]`, `$liste[0][1]` and `$liste[0][2]` are in real nothing else than a value `array(value, value, value)` (the inner array) which is assigned to `$liste[0]` (the outer array)

unsetting this (outer) array value `$liste[0]` is enough:

```
unset($liste[$id]);
```

If you care about the keys of this array (I see you **loop** from 0..n), you need to reindex your array using:

```
$liste = array_values($liste);
```

This will make your array behaving more like arrays normally do in other programming languages

Good practice is to use foreach instead of for. In this case you don't need to reindex:

```
for ($liste as $key=>$value){
    if ("$key"=="$id"){
        unset($liste[$key]);
    }
```

But anyway you don't have to loop through an array just for finding a key. It's enough doing this:

```
if (isset($liste[$id])) { /* optional: check if the key exists */ }

unset($liste[$id]);
```